# git branch contain multiple problems

Tags: git, branch

Hey guys I have a problem with the project I am currently working. I am currently on a feature branch and I worked on it for about 2 week. Now I have currently problems (it's a big project and it's my first internship :) ) and basically I want to return on the branch master (cause some of my problems are now fix on the branch Master ) but I want to keep all I have done. So what I should do? I want to go to the branch Master but I want to keep all my script and changes that I did on my feature branch without doing any merge on the Master. Thanks!

Comment: When you say I want to keep it, You mean that you want to comeback later and work on your feature branch ? is that it ? Or you want your changes on your feature branch to appear on master ?

Comment: I want to have the new version of master (the branch wich the production is working on )  without merging my branch into Master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found to resolve this type of issue it's best to create a new branch based off your work, and then merge master into that

```
# ancient history
git checkout -b featureA
   ...
   lots of local work
   ...
   now the upstream has breaking changes that I want

# create a new branch based off your featureA branch
git checkout -b featureB

# merge master into that and resolve any issues
git merge master
```

This keeps your original feature and the continued work separate (you can just let the original `featureA` branch persist indefinitely), while making it very obvious that there's been a big change.

You can then either merge your new branch back into your original branch when satisfied or let the original `featureA` branch stagnate or be deleted while continuing to work on your new `featureB` branch.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the situation I'd say.

If your goal is to keep your changes on your feature branch and you're sure that those changes are ready to commit, just `add` and `commit` them as usual you'll then be able to `checkout` to master.

now, if your goal is to just keep your changes without comitting them, you can use

```
git stash
```

Then you'll be able to checkout to master. When you want to comeback on your feature branch, `checkout` to it and  run

```
git stash apply
```

And your changes will re-appear.

**NOTE**

Don't run those commands if none of these situations are yours. Write a comment to be more specific to your problem and I will edit.

Comment: I want to compare my branch with the Master. I am thinking about create a new branch from master and I will merge this new branch with my feature branch. I am not sure if I can pop out my stash if I am not on my feature branch

Comment: What do you mean by _pop out_ ? And creating another branch berfore merging is certainly a good idea to prevent conflicts problems.

Comment: I mean to take what I stash from another branch

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the branch using the following command:

```
 git checkout <branch_name>
```

If you want to save the changes that you have made, you can use:

```
git stash
```

And to retrieve those changes back, you can use:

```
git stash pop
```

If you want to commit the changes on feature branch and want that commit on master branch, you can use cherry pick as well.

Answer (score 0):

(I assumed all your progress is already stored in one or more commits on your local branch)

First you have to get your branch up to date with the base you branched from (I'll assume it's called `master` and your remote `origin`, like in most git examples)

`git checkout master
git pull origin HEAD`

Then it's time to send your changes towards the master branch. Depending on your work setting, it could be either with a simple push (1) or by pull request (2).

1) On the most simple cases (arguably rare when many people work with the same remote repo), merge master on your local environnement and push your updated version of master to remote :

`git checkout master
git merge your_new_feature_branch`

(there'll possibly be conflicts to resolve at this point, but not necessarily. And even if so, you should know enough about your own changes to decide how to sort snippets in and out)

`git push origin HEAD`

2) If the master branch is set to refuse any push (as it is in some work environments), you might have to make a pull request on the remote environment to ask a reviewer with the required credentials to scan your changes and accept/refuse them.
In this case, you only have to push your feature branch on the remote beforehand :

`git checkout your_new_feature
git push origin HEAD`

Comment: I wasn't very clear... I don't want to do any merge at this point. But thanks! When I will do my merge I will do it!

Comment: @IsaacFiset Yes it's much clearer now, and indeed you should put your commited work on a branch until ready to merge in. Take care!